# Is the following possible in ASP.net / JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

i dont need code atm im just wondering if what i want to do is possible with asp.net. / js

I have a page which has an iframe in it. This iframe contains a page that contains a basic form and i cannot edit this page.

What i ideally want to do is this.

-User visits Master page

-User submits form in iframed page

-Postback from form submission in iframe triggers a postback in master page

-if (masterpage is postback) change iframe SRC to another random static page(this will just contain an image).

So basically what im asking, is - is it possible to:

A: trigger a postback on masterpage from a form submission in an iframe. (bearing in mind i cannot edit the iframed form page).

B: On the postback that would be caused by A on the masterpage. Change the SRC of the iframe to a different url.

again not looking for any code, but some resources would be appriciated so i can get an idea of what to start looking at.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as both pages are on the same domain you are allowed to call a function from the parents page in the iframe, just use `window.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Think of all the security flaws that would arise if this were possible.
(Phishing attacks).

You could probably detect when the iframe loads

Using jquery:

```
counter = 0;
$("iframe").load(function(){
    //The iframe has loaded or reloaded. 
    counter++;
    //take some action
    if(counter==2){
         __doPostback("","");
    }
});
```